# Convert type of Matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I have the following code to convert the "type" of the matrix using **cv::Mat.convertTo()** function in **OpenCV API**.

But when I show it using an **imshow()**, the images are completely different.

The converted image is completely grey.

However, the values in those images(**cv::Mat**) are the same.

I think I'm missing something very trivial here.

```
Mat x = imread("/home/jason/Desktop/1.png",0);
Mat y = Mat(x.rows,x.cols,CV_16S,Scalar(0));

x.convertTo(y,CV_16SC1, 1,0);

imshow("x",x);
imshow("y",y);
waitKey(0);

cout<<x.type()<<endl;
cout<<y.type()<<endl;

//verifying the values in the image.

cout<<"rows 10"<<x.row(10)<<endl;
cout<<"rows 10"<<y.row(10)<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing `CV_16S` image to the `imshow` (or its C equivalent) the pixel values are implicitly recalculated before the visualization by the formula v<sub>displayed</sub> = 128 + v<sub>image</sub>/256

So you probably need to multiply the image by some constant (256?) or convert it to `CV_8U` before the `imshow` call.

Comment: This is interesting. I just checked documentation. I thought it was very trivial to pay attention to. Do you have any clue on why it is done?

Comment: There are several reasons: 1) there are not so many devices which are able to display more than 8 bit per channel. 2) only BGR888 format is portable enough to be displayed on the all variety of systems where OpenCV is aimed to work. 3) GUI function in OpenCV are designed for the algorithm development and debugging but not for building real-world applications.